# Custom search query to show all replies in a post

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck, twitter-search

I use tweetdeck and it only loads some responses made to a post, so to see all replies I would like to create a new search column where the result would be the replies to that specific post, is there a way to create a query that satisfies this need?